# How do you make the input text disappear?

Tags: html, text, input, field, hide

I have an input field in which you can type some text. It has some default text:

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="Type some text here" maxlength="35" tabindex="10">
```

I want to make the default text disappear when the user clicks on the default text or inside the input field.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'd suggest using the placeholder attribute. The placeholder text will disappear when the user selects the text input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the placeholder attribute you can also try this:

```
<input type="text" value="Type some text here" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Type some text here') {this.value=''}" />
```

Comment: I like it! It's simple and I noticed this can also be used for older browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the placeholder attribute (placeholder="Your Text" instead of value="Your Text"):

```
<input type="text" id="text" maxlength="35" tabindex="10" placeholder="Type some text here">
```

Note: Placeholder attribute doesn't work in IE8/9, or Opera Mini (http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder).

Comment: id="text maxlength="35" ??

Answer (score 1):

Use the placeholder attribute

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="" maxlength="35" tabindex="10" placeholder="Type some text here">
```

If you want to support older browsers:

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="Type some text here" maxlength="35" tabindex="10" onclick="this.value = (this.value == 'Type some text here' ? '' : this.value);">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gLjt98af/

Answer (score 1):

1) Using placeholder attribute

You can use placeholder attribute as shown below. It will show as long as you don't click inside the text box. Once you type anything inside it, the text will disappear.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Type some text here" maxlength="35" tabindex="10">
```

2) Using java script function

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="Type some text here" maxlength="35" tabindex="10" 
onclick='cleartext()' onblur='settext()'>
```

JS

```
function cleartext(){
  document.getElementById('text').value= '';
}

function settext(){
  if(document.getElementById('text').value=== ''){
    document.getElementById('text').value= 'Type some text here' 
  }
}
```